# Get missing dates of dictionary and sort it

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the next dictionary and I need to get the missing periods between the determinate period, in other words, get the period between the end date of one period and the start date of the next one.

```
{'0': {'enddate': u'2015/08/31',
       'startdate': u'2015/01/01'},
 '1': {'enddate': u'2018/10/31',
       'startdate': u'2017/01/01'},
 '2': {'enddate': u'2019/03/29',
       'startdate': u'2019/01/01'}}
```

**`The function who get this data is the next:`**

```
def periods(periods):

    total_periods={}
    for period in periods:
        total_periods[period] = {}
        for  startdate in periods[period][0]:
            total_periods[period]['startdate'] = startdate
        for enddate in periods[period][-1]:
            total_periods[period]['enddate'] = enddate
```

**`I have the next code that get the missing periods but i cant to order whith my expect results.`**

```
gaps={}
s=[]
e=[]
for i in period:
    s.append(datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(period[i]['enddate'],'%Y/%m/%d')+timedelta(days=1),'%Y/%m/%d'))
    e.append(datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(period[i]['startdate'],'%Y/%m/%d')+timedelta(days=-1),'%Y/%m/%d'))

for i in range(len(s)):
    if i==len(s)-1:
        break
    d={}
    d['startdate']=s[i]
    d['enddate']=e[i+1]
    gaps[str(i)]=d
```

**`The output of these code is the next:`**

```
{'0': {'enddate': '2014/12/31', 'startdate': '2018/11/01'},
 '1': {'enddate': '2018/12/31', 'startdate': '2015/09/01'}}
```

But is wrong, because i need the next results:

```
{'0': {'enddate': '2016/12/31', 'startdate': '2015/09/01'},
 '1': {'enddate': '2018/12/31', 'startdate': '2018/11/01'}}
```

Hope I explain correctly and clear.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
for i in period:
```

Dictionaries are not ordered, so there is no guarantee of what order the items will be accessed when you loop over them.  The rest of your code assumes they will com in order.  Try this:

```
for i in sorted(period):
```

but be aware that if you have more elements sorting strings like '8', '9', '10', '11' probably won't do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think you didn't explain quite clearly how you determine the gaps in your periods. I looked through your code and I think this is what you want:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

periods = {'0': {'enddate': u'2015/08/31', 'startdate': u'2015/01/01'},
            '1': {'enddate': u'2018/10/31', 'startdate': u'2017/01/01'},
            '2': {'enddate': u'2019/03/29', 'startdate': u'2019/01/01'}}

gaps = {}
for i in range(len(periods) - 1):
    gap_period = {}
    gap_period['startdate'] = datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(periods[str(i)]['enddate'], r'%Y/%m/%d') + timedelta(days=1), r'%Y/%m/%d')
    gap_period['enddate'] = datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(periods[str(i+1)]['startdate'], r'%Y/%m/%d') + timedelta(days=-1), r'%Y/%m/%d')
    gaps[str(i)] = gap_period

>>>gaps
{'0': {'startdate': '2015/09/01', 'enddate': '2016/12/31'}, '1': {'startdate': '2018/11/01', 'enddate': '2018/12/31'}}
```

**Note:** Your gap period is defined by the day after the end_date of *Period i-1* and the day before the start_date of *Period i*

Comment: Hi, i got this error:  TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: @hmar My solution doesn't make use of _lists_. Are you sure it's not from the other parts in your code?

Comment: I don't think so:     gap_period['startdate'] = datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(periods[int(i)]['enddate'], r'%Y/%m/%d') + timedelta(days=1), r'%Y/%m/%d')
KeyError: 0 TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: `periods[int(i)]` - why did you change it to `int(i)`? Your dictionary keys are numeric strings. Additionally, `periods` is supposed to be a _dict_ and not a _list_?

Comment: @kerwey Sorry i tried to change str to int but the result is the same. Periods is a dict, not a list : /    --->  gap_period['startdate'] = datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(periods[str(i)]['enddate'], r'%Y/%m/%d') + timedelta(days=1), r'%Y/%m/%d')
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: I just found the error, the name dict was wrong. It works! Thanks you so much dude!

Answer (score 0):

Beware that some methods won't work if the periods overlap. If the periods overlap, you need a more sophisticated algorithm.

First, a few definitions:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta

>>> dates_by_num = {'0': {'enddate': '2015/08/31', 'startdate':'2015/01/01'}, '1': {'enddate': '2018/10/31', 'startdate': '2017/01/01'}, '2': {'enddate': '2019/03/29', 'startdate': '2019/01/01'}}
>>> def to_date(s): return datetime.strptime(s, r'%Y/%m/%d')
>>> def to_string(d): return datetime.strftime(d, r'%Y/%m/%d')
```

The key idea is to sort all the dates and to keep a value indicating if it's a start (`1`) or end (`-1`) date.

```
>>> dates = sorted(d_s  for _, v in dates_by_num.items() for d_s in ((to_date(v['startdate']), 1), (to_date(v['enddate']), -1)))
>>> dates
[(datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 31, 0, 0), -1), (datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 31, 0, 0), -1), (datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0), 1), (datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 29, 0, 0), -1)]
```

Now, we iterate over the dates and keep a count `c` of the number of intervals we are in: every start date, `c` increases and every end date, `c` decreases, hence `c` is the number of start dates minus the number of end dates. We are out of all the intervals when (and only when) `c == 0`.

```
>>> gaps = []
>>> last_c, last_d = 1, 0
>>> c = 0
>>> for d, s in dates:
...     c += s
...     assert c >= 0 # c is the number of intervals we are in
...     if last_c == 0 and d - last_d > timedelta(days=1): # we were out of all the intervals
...         gaps.append({'startdate': to_string(last_d+timedelta(days=1)), 'endate': to_string(d+timedelta(days=-1))})
...     last_c, last_d = c, d
...
```

I added a test to remove void gaps (`d - last_d > timedelta(days=1)`). To get the presentation you want:

```
>>> {str(i): d for i, d in enumerate(gaps)}
{'0': {'startdate': '2015/09/01', 'endate': '2016/12/31'}, '1': {'startdate': '2018/11/01', 'endate': '2018/12/31'}}
```

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def to_date(s): return datetime.strptime(s, r'%Y/%m/%d')
def to_string(d): return datetime.strftime(d, r'%Y/%m/%d')

def find_gaps(dates_by_num):
    dates = sorted(d_s  for _, v in dates_by_num.items() for d_s in ((to_date(v['startdate']), 1), (to_date(v['enddate']), -1)))
    gaps = []
    last_c, last_d = 1, 0
    c = 0
    for d, s in dates:
        c += s
        assert c >= 0 # c is the number of interval we are in
        if last_c == 0 and d - last_d > timedelta(days=1): # we were not in any interval
            gaps.append({'startdate': to_string(last_d+timedelta(days=1)), 'endate': to_string(d+timedelta(days=-1))})
        last_c, last_d = c, d
    return {str(i): d for i, d in enumerate(gaps)}
```

Examples:

```
>>> find_gaps({'0': {'enddate': '2018/08/31', 'startdate':'2015/01/01'}, '1': {'enddate': '2018/10/31', 'startdate': '2017/01/01'}, '2': {'enddate': '2019/03/29', 'startdate': '2019/01/01'}})
{'0': {'startdate': '2018/11/01', 'endate': '2018/12/31'}}
>>> find_gaps({'0': {'enddate': '2016/12/31', 'startdate':'2015/01/01'}, '1': {'enddate': '2018/10/31', 'startdate': '2017/01/01'}, '2': {'enddate': '2019/03/29', 'startdate': '2019/01/01'}})
{'0': {'startdate': '2018/11/01', 'endate': '2018/12/31'}}
>>> find_gaps({'0': {'enddate': '2016/08/31', 'startdate':'2015/01/01'}, '1': {'enddate': '2019/10/31', 'startdate': '2017/01/01'}, '2': {'enddate': '2019/03/29', 'startdate': '2019/01/01'}})
{'0': {'startdate': '2016/09/01', 'endate': '2016/12/31'}}
```

Answer (score -1):

You did not tell which version of Python you are using, but be aware that order of elements in dictionary is not preserved. If you want dictionary to keep the order you should use `collections.OrderedDict` instead: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict